# Using TortoiseHg's Repository explorer

Tags: windows, mercurial, tortoise-svn, tortoise-hg

I'm coming from a TortoiseSVN background and decided to give TortoiseHg a try. One thing I got really used to with TortoiseSVN was the SVN Repo-Explorer, which worked quite similarly to Windows Explorer. However, when I tried to use TortoiseHg's Repository Explorer, what I got was something else, it was more like TortoiseSVN's Show Log. It showed me what the recent commits were and what files were changed and even had nifty graphs. However, I'm still left wanting for TortoiseSVN's Repo-Explorer.

Does TortoiseHg have anything like this? How am I supposed to poke around the Repository if I can only view changed stuff?

**EDIT:** Answered on SO: [Using TortoiseHg’s Repository explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399807/using-tortoisehgs-repository-explorer).

Comment: Can someone close this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Answered by Benny Jobigan over at StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399807/using-tortoisehgs-repository-explorer)